# Fetch data for a specific field in Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have a JSON URI which I am using as a data source. I am writing a web API wherein I need to retrieve the data for any of the specific field which user inputs.

The problem is that I am not sure how to use the "element" field which is nothing but name of the field which user inputs to filter the JSON data source.

For example, below JSON is my data source and I need to fetch data only for table_no. So the user will input the field as `table_no` and the response should only show data with `table_no` only.

```json
"data": [

    {

        "order": 1,
        "table_no": 94683,
        "table_book_date": "20240103100000",
    },
    
    {
        "order": 2,
        "table_no": 94544,
        "table_book_date": "20240103100000",
     }
    
    ]
```

I have this C# code where "element" is an input which can be any field. Here it is `table_no`, but not sure how to use it to filter my JSON data.

```cs
 [HttpGet("[action]/{element}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string element)
 {
     try
     {
         var restaurantData= await DeSerializeJsonData(element);
         return Ok(new RestaurantDataResponse()
         {
             RestaurantResponse = restaurantData.data
         }

             );
     }
     catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
     {
         return BadRequest($"Error");
     }
 }
private async Task<RestaurantData> DeSerializeJsonData(string element)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<RestaurantData\>($"<json url>.json");
        return response;
    }
}
```

The final response should look like--

```json
{ "data": [ 
    { "table_no": 94683, }, 
    { "table_no": 94544, } 
] }
```

Comment: I suggest you propose what the response JSON you want should look like. By the way, neither of your spellings of _restaurant_ are correct. You might also want to look into _GraphQL_

Comment: Respose json should like below with data of table_no only--data":  [

 {

        "table_no": 94683,
 },
    
    {
        "table_no": 94544,
     }
    
  ]

Comment: Add it to your question

Comment: [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) can help you to control the JSON that is created. You put the `restaurantData.data` into an anonymous object and then return it.

Comment: I want to match the inputted element name with the property in my json data. Not sure how Anoynmous Types will help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you aren't going to be returning RestarauntData if you want the output to just be a filtered field from the restaurant data based on the "element" value you pass in. So the return type cannot be a static type unless you're happy for the name of the property to be static such as "selectedValue" optionally with a value name to indicate the "element" you filtered out:

```
{ "selectedValue": 94683, "valueName": "table_no" }
{ "selectedValue": 94684, "valueName": "table_no" }
```

Spmething like this can be achieved by declaring a type for the above data:

```
[Serializable]
public class FilteredData
{
    public object SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public string ValueName { get; set; }
}
```

... then populating:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = data["data"].Select(x => new FilteredData { SelectedValue = x[element], ValueName = element }).ToList();
return result;
```

However, if instead you wanted to return the JSON string then you could have a method return the desired JObject:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = data["data"].Select(x => new { __fieldName__ = x[element] }).ToList();
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
jsonResult = jsonResult.Replace("__fieldName__", element);

return jsonResult;
```

This would return the desired:

```
[
    { "table_no": 94683, }, 
    { "table_no": 94544, } 
]
```

It's a bit of a hack with the `string.Replace` since the `Select` needs a constant string for the field name returned which we use a placeholder that is then replaced in the resulting JSON. You may need to tweak the return if you want the "data" labelled [] container array.

Comment: Thanks. I would mark this as answered shortly. Just an issue I am facing here is in the below code--                                                                                                              
 JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = data["data"].Select(x => new FilteredData { SelectedValue = x[element], ValueName = element }).ToList();
return result;. Here, SelectedValue I am getting as [] and not the value. If I cast it to a particular type then I am getting the value. But I cannot do that because type is not known and hence SelectedValue is of type object.

Comment: I serialized the result object and returned it in response and now I can see the value.